# Parse an f-style interpolated string to recover arguments

Tags: scala, parsing, string-formatting, string-interpolation

What's the best way to create the complement for an f-style string interpolation, i.e. a way to parse the arguments/numbers in a formatted string?

E.g.

```
val format = "frame%04d.png"
val i = 123
val out = f"frame$i%04d.png"
assert(out == "frame0123.png")

def parse(s: String, pat: String): Int = ???

val j = parse(out, format)
assert(j == 123)
```

I know I can manually construct a reg-exp, I just wonder if there is a general approach with f-style interpolated strings.

I was hoping for something simple like:

```
val f"frame$j%04d.png" = out
```

But

> error: macro method f is not a case class, nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq member

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this nice post](http://hootenannylas.blogspot.ru/2013/02/pattern-matching-with-string.html) about using interpolators as pattern matchers so this is starting point for you:

```
object StringMatcher {
  val ZeroFillDec = "%0(\\d+)d(.*)".r
  val SimpleDec = "%(\\d+)d(.*)".r
  val String = "%s(.*)".r

  def patternize(part: String) = part match {
    case ZeroFillDec(len, rest) => f"(\\d{${len.toInt}})$rest"
    case SimpleDec(len, rest) => f"(\\d{1,${len.toInt}})$rest"
    case String(rest) => f"(.*)$rest"
    case rest => f"(.*)$rest"
  }
}

implicit class StringMatcher(sc: StringContext) {

  import StringMatcher.patternize

  object pat {
    def unapplySeq(s: String): Option[Seq[String]] = {
      val re = (sc.parts.head ++ (sc.parts.tail map patternize)).mkString.r
      re.unapplySeq(s)
    }
  }
}
```

Using that, code

```
val out = "frame0123_023.png"
val pat"frame$j%04d_$i%03d.png" = out
```

assigns

```
j: String = 0123
i: String = 023
```